# API Mercadolibre

Tags: api, sdk, mercadolibre

Hola estoy utilizando la API de MercadoLibre para publicar Inmuebles, el problema que estoy teniendo es que las mismas finalizan automaticamente, estuve leyendo la documentacion y para Casas y Departamentos establecen una caducidad de entre 45 y 180 dias y cumplido ese tiempo finaliza la publicacion, lo que quisiera saber es si existe alguna forma de hacer la republicacion con la API, alguien tuvo este problema? espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega todo el código que estás usando, incluye las referencias de la documentación, con estos elementos aumentas las chances de obtener respuesta y evitas que te cierren la pregunta por efectos de baja calidad. Saludos.